# Reuse already loaded header view in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I use Google ads on

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

In each section of a UITableView after 4 cells I want to show the ads. Every time it takes time to reload the ads. When I scroll if I'm in first section, the ads load. After I move to another section, new ads load when I go back to first section. I want to reuse the old ads view for the first section only. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load google Ads before the tableview setup

In View DidLoad method load the addFirst before populating the tableviewCells

```
 [self loadGoogleAdMobBanner];

-(void)loadGoogleAdMobBanner
{

}
```

In Tableview Cell for the row method is as follows:

```
GoogleAdsCategoryCell *myGoogleAdCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoogleAdsCategoryCell"];

        if (myGoogleAdCell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib_Array = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"GoogleAdsCategoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
            myGoogleAdCell = [nib_Array objectAtIndex:0];

        }
         [myGoogleAdCell.bannerView addSubview:_homeBannerView];
         return  myGoogleAdCell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is the approach that you will use that is normally adopted in case of loading images.

May be you can cache (if possible) all the loaded ads and when you scroll up or down the table view, show that cached ads against each cell.